# Year to Century Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem: Given a year, return the century it is in. The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200, etc.

My code:

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    century = year/100 
    decimal = int(str(century[-2:-1]))
    integer = int(str(century)[:2])

    if decimal > 0:
        return integer + 1
    else:
        return integer

print(centuryFromYear(2017))
```

This doesn't seem to work in certain cases, for example, when year = 2001 or year = 2000.

Would anyone be able to provide a more simple piece of code?

Answer (score 11):

You can use integer division, operator `//` in python 3:

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    return (year) // 100 + 1    # 1 because 2017 is 21st century, and 1989 = 20th century

print(centuryFromYear(2017))  # --> 21
```

**Please note:** This does not account for century BC, and it uses a cut off date at `Dec 31st xy99` where it is sometimes strictly defined as `Dec 31st xy00`
[more info here](https://www.joc.com/how-count-centuries_19970102.html)

if you wanted to set the cutoff on `Dec 31st xy00`, which is more strict, you would likely want to do like this:

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    return (year - 1) // 100 + 1    # 1 because 2017 is 21st century, and 1989 = 20th century

print(centuryFromYear(2017))  # --> 21
```

Comment: You need (year - 1) or you put multiples of 100 in the wrong century.

Comment: That's a good point, but apparently not the OP's top priority, which was finding a way to do integer division... I left a note warning for this, and a link to a discussion about "practices" (best and less best) in this domain. This is rather lame nit-picking, especially that it doesn't seem you read my answer in its entirety!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple one-liner solution:

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    return (year + 99) // 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ceiling function available in 'math' module to get the desired solution.

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
 return math.ceil(year/100)
```

Answer (score 1):

With integer division, works properly both for 2000 and for 2017:

```
1 + (year - 1) // 100
```

Comment: "properly" is a misnomer, telling an opinion;  "strictly" is surely more appropriate. The commonly accepted practice, which is indeed inaccurate, is to set the cut off for centuries on `Dec 31st  xx99`

Comment: @Reblochon Masque There is no 0-th year in our calendar, so 1st century is 1-100, 2nd is 101-200 and so on. Yes, I know that some people celebrated 3rd millennium twice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('Find the Century = '))
```

Divide the number by 100

```
century = a // 100
```

Check if the year belongs the same century

```
if(a%100 != 0):
      century = century + 1
print(century)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which works for 0-9999 which is more in the lines of your attempts.

```
year = 2018
cent = int(str(year).zfill(4)[:2])+1
print(cent)
```

Returns:

```
21
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the correct century output:

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    return -(-year // 100)
```

It uses negative floor division:

```
1700 // 100 = 17
1701 // 100 = 17
- (-1701 // 100) = 18
```

It does a floor division on -1701//100 which is -18.

It works for all years and is 1 line only.

Answer (score -1):

First start by subtracting 1 from the `year` in context

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    return (year - 1) // 100 + 1
```

Works for implementing the following examples:

```
print(centuryFromYear(2000))  # --> 20
print(centuryFromYear(2001))  # --> 21
print(centuryFromYear(2017))  # --> 21
```

Comment: Duplicate of answer from 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356843/2745495

Answer (score -1):

THIS WORKED FOR ME:

```
def whatCenturyIsX(x):

    #turn our input into a string for modification
    x = str(x)
    #separate the characters of x into a list for further use
    xlist = list(x)
    #set a boolean to contatin negativity or positivity of the number
    #if the "minus" sign is in x, set the boolean to true and remove the "minus" for easier handling of the variable
    #(the minus doesn't tell us anything anymore because we already set the boolean)
    negative = False
    if "-" in xlist:
        negative = True
        xlist.remove("-")
        for i in xlist:
            x += i

    #to define what century year x is in, we are going to take the approach of adding 1 to the first n characters, when N is the number of digits - 2. This is proved. So:
    
    #also, we need the string to be at least 4 characters, so we add 0's if there are less

    if len(xlist) >= 4:
        pass
        
    
    else:
        if len(xlist) == 3:
            xlist.insert(0, 0)
            x = ""
            for i in xlist:
                x += str(i)
        elif len(xlist) == 2:
            xlist.insert(0, 0)
            xlist.insert(1, 0)
            x = ""
            for i in xlist:
                x += str(i)
        elif len(xlist) == 1:
            
            xlist.insert(0, 0)
            xlist.insert(1, 0)
            xlist.insert(2, 0)
            x = ""
            for i in xlist:
                x += str(i)
        

    n = len(xlist) - 2
    #j is the number formed by the first n characters.
    j = ""
    for k in range(0, n):
        #add the first n characters to j
        j += str(xlist[k])
        #finally form the century by adding 1 to j and calling it c.
    c = int(j) + 1



    #for the final return statement, we add a "-" and "B.C." if negative is true, and "A.C." if negative is false.
    if negative:
        xlist.insert(0, "-")
        x = ""
        for i in xlist:
            x += str(i)
        return(str(x) + " is en the century " + str(c) + " B.C.")
    else:
        return(str(x) + " is en the century " + str(c) + " A.C.")
```